# Cannot find the way to update to latest GHDL version

Tags: vhdl

My problem is that I'm just trying to get some lateral knowledge aside university, so I stumbled upon VHDL and I am still fascinated by this language, but as I started researching, I've noticed that it's more like alchemy, every tutorial is either at a braindead difficulty level or skips the exact thing I'm trying to understand, from installation to the actual language, but that's not such an issue.

The real issue is downloading the installer for Windows from the GHDL's site. *It's not updated*; as far as I know the latest update of GHDL is either the 0.37 or the 1.0.0, I really don't know, since the Github page has downloads from 0.37 which are system-related and the downloads from the 1.0.0 is just source code or something.

So I download the 0.37 (which is still newer than mine -0.29.1-), and then the wiki's instruction clearly says "run set_ghdl_path.bat" and another one which I don't remember, so how do I run a bat file? And more importantly, how do I run a bat file which doesn't exists, neither in my extracted zip nor in the original zip?

Searching for info is like trying to kill a fly with a knife while being blind, deaf, and having lost a hand, so pretty please, can anyone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl#getting-ghdl

Comment: Already read that page a lot of times, but it didn't work, due to this problem I moved to verilog and I'm having way less problems, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

GHDL is built nightly as part of this package as well

https://github.com/YosysHQ/oss-cad-suite-build

(website doesnt say it really, but its in the tar balls you download)

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- As we can reason from the OP's question, it needs a bit more than just a source. Would you mind to [edit] your answer and add some steps for that poor soul who doesn't even know how to execute a batch? ;-) Who knows, it could bring you some upvotes!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't worked either, as said in another comment i moved to verilog, tho